# How to know where to put those arrows ↗ ↘ to represent the intonation?

Tags: intonation

Hello at first I thought that it is only to count each syllable of a word very slowly but I think I am wrong, but I can not understand the explanation of Luca Lampariello is because I am a native speaker of Spanish.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r05ropOnt3s

Do these arrows ↗ ↘ apply in all languages?

I myself as a beginner can I place those arrows ↗ ↘ or is it recommended that a native speaker do it?

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of those IPA letters is pretty open-ended: they stand for "global rise" and "global fall". If the overall intonation goes up, you pick one symbol, and if it goes down, you pick the other. You can't be more specific than that without specifying a particular language and tradition of analysis. There are many traditions for transcribing intonation in English, and few for Bambara (probably only one). Only some traditions use those arrows: ToBI and ToDI use tone letters with modifier diacritics. There is a version of ToBI for Spanish (where you would not use the arrows), and an older classical study by Bowen which uses numbers of up/down arrows (upstep and downstep in current IPA). So you would have to investigate the details of the theory that you're working in.